# Return elements that match as an array

Tags: ruby, testing, webdriver, watir

I am new to the Watir world, having used webdriver and geb in a previous company.  I want to know if Watir offers any method that is analogous to the get_elements method from webdriver.  See below for an example.

Imagine the following html exists within a larger page

```
<div class="someClass">someText</div>
<div class="someClass">someMoreText</div>
<div class="someClass">evenMoreText</div>
```

I want make some assertion against each of the divs by locating all elements of the given class and iterating through them.  Using webdriver, I could do it like this:

```
elements = driver.get_elements(:css, ".someClass")
elements.each do |element|
    //some assert on element
end
```

Does Watir provide an equivalent construct?  I can't find anything useful in the Watir documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
elements = driver.elements(:css => '.someClass')
```

Or if you know they are all divs, you should do:

```
elements = driver.divs(:css => '.someClass')
```

Both of these methods would return a collection of elements that match your criteria. In the first case it would match any tag type, where as the second case the results would be limited to divs.

Then, with either of the above, you can iterate the same way:

```
elements.each do |element|
    //some assert on element
end
```

Comment: Justin, you seem to have typo there, it should be .someClass - you're missing the dot.

Comment: Thanks @JarmoPertman. Though I think the typo is actually that :css should have been :class.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `:css` locator i'd recommend you to use `:class` locator instead, since it is usually faster and makes your tests more readable:

```
elements = driver.divs(:class => 'someClass')
```

Also, don't forget `:id`, `:name`, `:text` and others.